# GCP Internal https load balancer health check issue

Tags: google-cloud-platform, networking, cloud

We deployed internal https load balancer in GCP. For application we did not configure ssl it works with in browser like https://instanceip:443/hb. The health check is of type https for load balancer. When we try https://instanceip:443/hb in browser we are getting ok 200 response with SSL issue. When we configured load balancer health check is failing even though config is correct like request path is /hb and port 443. Is this because SSL is not configured?. And also after lb is configured when we try with lb ip we are getting no healthy upstream is this because of health check is failing (https://lbip:443/hb). Thanks

Answer (score 1):

SSL is not configured for your application. When you access the https://instanceip:443/hb on the browser you are getting an error message because the browser needs a valid SSL certificate from the server.

You have only configured the health checks to use HTTPS, the load balancer expects a valid SSL certificate from the backend server.

No healthy upstream error because the health check is down so the load balancer is not able to find a healthy backed instance to route traffic. Check the logs for the reason for failure. Change the health checks to HTTP instead of HTTPS.